# How to release Private cocoapods versions?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am releasing private cocoapod versions by using github. Here problem is If i release new version, old version is not working. I mean user is unable to install old version of my Pod.

Ex: New version is 1.2.3
Old version is 1.2.2

User can't able to install 1.2.2 version. Please help me how to maintain all versions. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am no expert with CocoaPods, but they interest me, however how would CocoaPods know to get a certain version of a pod from one repo (your private one, for example) and another version of the pod from another repo (the public one)?  Is it supposed to search all the repos it knows about for that particular version or does it just decide that a certain repo will always be used for a particular pod?  (genuine question). Anyway if the latter it sounds like you need to blat any local pod cache and re-init.

Comment: All versions will be in my private repo only. If I update a new pod, as new Release, old pods are not getting installed.

Comment: Cocoapods uses tagging to identify the available versions. As long as your releases are tagged correctly then your users should be able to specify a specific version in their pod file. Could you edit your question to show the pod file they are using and what error message they are getting